# How to get the values of data-* attributes in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, custom-data-attribute

I have a button which when clicked opens up a modal, and the content to show in the modal is based on the data-attributes passed to the button.

My button,

```
<button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#someModal" :data-id=item.id :data-name=item.name>
  Edit
</button>
```

In my modal, I have some buttons and when clicked I should call a vuejs function with a parameter, which is the data-attribute.

My modal button,

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
        @click.prevent="deleteItem()" data-dismiss="modal">
        Delete
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
    </button>
</div>
```

Here I have to pass a parameter to `deleteItem()`, and that parameter is the `data-id` which I get from the button above.

Code for Modal

```
    <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="deleteContent">
                        Are you Sure you want to delete ?
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn actionBtn btn-danger"
                            @click.prevent="deleteItem()"
                            data-dismiss="modal">
                            Delete <span id="footer_action_button"
                                class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
                            data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the modal you're using?

Comment: Posted the code for modal, I need to pass a parameter to the function in modal footer button.

Comment: When you pass props as kebab case for the component, Vue js changes them to camel case, so `data-id` is available as `this.dataId` in your component

Answer (score 9):

## HTML

```
<button type="button" @click.prevent="deleteItem()" :data-id="1" data-dismiss="modal">
Delete <span id="footer_action_button" class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span>
</button>
```

## Vue

```
methods:{
  deleteItem: function(){
    var id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(id) // 1
  }
}
```

## Here is the demo https://codepen.io/maab16/pen/jONZpVG

Answer (score 6):

I recommend doing a `console.log(this)` inside a component function, then calling that function on a button click so you can inspect all the properties of the component.

(See the attached image, below, for example output of the above `console.log` statement.)

This shows you that amongst others, you have access to the `$el` property holding the DOM element. Which opens up a whole lot of possibilities, such as being able to add the following code to the `mounted` lifecycle hook of your component:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this);
  this.myAttribute = this.$el.getAttribute('data-attribute-name');
},
```

And for this example, this.myAttribute would have been defined in (for example) your data property:

```
// This value gets attributed during an earlier lifecycle hook.
// It will be overridden in the component's mounted() lifecycle hook.
data() {
  return {
    myAttribute: 'defaultvalue'
  }
}
```

[Vue.js (v2) Lifecycle hooks documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

---

Example output when executing `console.log(this)` inside a component:

[image]

Comment: It is possible to use `this.$el.getAttribute('data-*')` function in `beforeMount` hook. In such case you can specify `null` for properties instead of default values in `data` function.

Comment: For any 1.x users, `compiled` looks like the earliest lifecycle hook with `this.$el` populated such that you can use it like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the "item.id" like this too:

```
<button type="button" @click="deleteItem(item.id)">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option will be bind the id to the delete button as well

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
        @click.prevent="deleteItem(this)"  :data-id=item.id data-dismiss="modal">
        Delete
    </button>
```

Comment: When add this,  i get the following error `[Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in root instance)`

Comment: make sure the scope extends the button as well

Comment: Yea the button is in the scope itself.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) read-only property to retrieve the values of [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) (`data-*`) on elements.

Here is a live demonstration available on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vbjuxd?file=src%2FApp.vue).

HTML

```
<button
  type="button"
  @click.prevent="deleteItem"
  :data-id="6904888"
  :data-name="'Penny Liu'"
>
  Delete
</button>
```

Vue

```
methods: {
  deleteItem(event) {
    const { id, name } = event.target.dataset;
  },
},
```